How to construct a networkx graph from a dictionary with format `node: {neighbor: weight}`?
I have the following dictionary that contains node-neighbor-weight pairs:
graph = {
    "A": {"B": 3, "C": 3},
    "B": {"A": 3, "D": 3.5, "E": 2.8},
    "C": {"A": 3, "E": 2.8, "F": 3.5},
    "D": {"B": 3.5, "E": 3.1, "G": 10},
    "E": {"B": 2.8, "C": 2.8, "D": 3.1, "G": 7},
    "F": {"G": 2.5, "C": 3.5},
    "G": {"F": 2.5, "E": 7, "D": 10},
}

The visual representation of the graph is this:

How do I go from that dictionary to a networkx graph object:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

# YOUR SUGGESTION HERE #


You need to add the dictionary as edges to the graph
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

graph = {
    "A": {"B": 3, "C": 3},
    "B": {"A": 3, "D": 3.5, "E": 2.8},
    "C": {"A": 3, "E": 2.8, "F": 3.5},
    "D": {"B": 3.5, "E": 3.1, "G": 10},
    "E": {"B": 2.8, "C": 2.8, "D": 3.1, "G": 7},
    "F": {"G": 2.5, "C": 3.5},
    "G": {"F": 2.5, "E": 7, "D": 10},
}

G = nx.Graph()
for node, neighbors in graph.items():
    for neighbor, weight in neighbors.items():
        G.add_edge(node, neighbor, weight=weight)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
plt.show()



I think this is more elegant.

You can create a graph with G = nx.Graph(graph), but this won't keep the weights.
One possibility to handle the weights would be to rework the input with a dictionary comprehension and from_dict_of_dicts:
G = nx.from_dict_of_dicts({k: {n: {'weight': w} for n, w in d.items()}
                           for k,d in graph.items()})

Or through the constructor:
G = nx.Graph({k: {n: {'weight': w} for n, w in d.items()}
              for k,d in graph.items()})

Output graph:

Intermediate dictionary:
{'A': {'B': {'weight': 3}, 'C': {'weight': 3}},
 'B': {'A': {'weight': 3}, 'D': {'weight': 3.5}, 'E': {'weight': 2.8}},
 'C': {'A': {'weight': 3}, 'E': {'weight': 2.8}, 'F': {'weight': 3.5}},
 'D': {'B': {'weight': 3.5}, 'E': {'weight': 3.1}, 'G': {'weight': 10}},
 'E': {'B': {'weight': 2.8},
  'C': {'weight': 2.8},
  'D': {'weight': 3.1},
  'G': {'weight': 7}},
 'F': {'G': {'weight': 2.5}, 'C': {'weight': 3.5}},
 'G': {'F': {'weight': 2.5}, 'E': {'weight': 7}, 'D': {'weight': 10}}}

